# Freeze top row splits the screen

Tags: vba, excel

I recorded a macro which just uses the inbuilt "Freeze Top Row" option in the Freeze Panes dropdown in Excel 2007.

The code as viewed in the editor was as follows:

```
With ActiveWindow
    .SplitColumn = 0
    .SplitRow = 1
End With
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

However, when I run this code from the editor it splits the screen as opposed to freezing the panes. It gives the desired effect, but the "split" option is selected on the ribbon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the behavior you described is correct.
I have no answer to that ATM. But below works freezing the top row.
Same effect using the commented code.

```
Rows("2:2").Select '~~> Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

**Note:** Above won't work if ScreenUpdating is False and then set True later in the code.

Comment: ok thanks for the code. its a bit weird, but nothing that effects the performance of my code, just one of those oddities that i noticed.

Answer (score 0):

To freeze the top row, use the following code:

```
Rows("1:1").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
```

To freeze more rows than just the top one, change the `Rows("1:1").Select` to the desired row.

You'll need to activate the sheet that you want to freeze row on. The below code is a sample procedure that you could use:

```
Public Sub fFreezeRow(wsName As String, intRow As Integer)

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
    .Activate
    .Rows(intRow & ":" & intRow).Select
End With

ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

End Sub
```

Comment: this doesnt work for me, it freezes the panes in the centre of the sheet?

Comment: I've updated my answer, you'll need to activate the sheet to use `Select`.

Comment: thanks. for some reason it still doesnt seem to work this end. with that code, it seems to select all cells in the sheet but doesnt apply the freeze panes at all. v weird.

Comment: Same happens to me, just select the cells